# Exception on php mb_ereg_match

Tags: php, regex, exception

I am using mb_ereg_match to validate that a domain name does not containe illegal characters.

I am using this regex:

```
'/:\/\/|www[.][a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-ΩάέύήίόώϋϊΐΰΆΈΏΊΎΌΉΫΪÀàÂâÆæÄäÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÖöÙùÛûÜüŸÿ0-9]+[.]|^[-]+|^[.]+|[-]+$|[.]+$|[-]{2,}|[.]{2,}|[^\w-.]|-[.]|[.]-/u'
```

Which as you can se by your self contain all the basic latin chars, nums, France's letters and the whole Greek alphabet.

My validation code is the following:

```
$utf8 = (mb_detect_encoding($value) == 'UTF-8') ? TRUE : FALSE;

if ($utf8){
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $matches = mb_ereg_match($pattern, $value);
}else{
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
}
```

I am trying to validate this:

```
'geoσσσrge.cσσσσσm.gr'
```

Here is the error I get:

```
mb_ereg_match(): mbregex compile err: empty range in char class
```

The error does not appear all the time. Usually it apears when it stays idle for a long time and after I refresh my page returns to normal.

I don't know how to handle this error or how to approche it in order to find the source of the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It usually means that $value is empty, which is weird in your example.

Comment: I agree that it is wierd since I hard coded on function call.

Comment: Why don't you always use `preg_match`, but with the `u` flag?

Comment: It throughs an exception for the encoding when used on Greek alphabet. But I cant remember the exception and why. I just found a solution that works and I go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` through `.` is not a range it can understand. Escape the `-` or move the `-` to the start; `[^\w-.]`.

```
$pattern = '/:\/\/|www[.][a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-ΩάέύήίόώϋϊΐΰΆΈΏΊΎΌΉΫΪÀàÂâÆæÄäÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÖöÙùÛûÜüŸÿ0-9]+[.]|^[-]+|^[.]+|[-]+$|[.]+$|[-]{2,}|[.]{2,}|[^\w\-.]|-[.]|[.]-/u';
$value = 'geoσσσrge.cσσσσσm.gr';

$utf8 = (mb_detect_encoding($value) == 'UTF-8') ? TRUE : FALSE;

if ($utf8){
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $matches = mb_ereg_match($pattern, $value);
}else{
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
}
```

or

```
$pattern = '/:\/\/|www[.][a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-ΩάέύήίόώϋϊΐΰΆΈΏΊΎΌΉΫΪÀàÂâÆæÄäÇçÉéÈèÊêËëÎîÏïÔôŒœÖöÙùÛûÜüŸÿ0-9]+[.]|^[-]+|^[.]+|[-]+$|[.]+$|[-]{2,}|[.]{2,}|[^-\w.]|-[.]|[.]-/u';
$value = 'geoσσσrge.cσσσσσm.gr';

$utf8 = (mb_detect_encoding($value) == 'UTF-8') ? TRUE : FALSE;

if ($utf8){
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $matches = mb_ereg_match($pattern, $value);
}else{
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);
}
```

Comment: You are right I should have escaped the "-". Thank you very much.